# How do I make a withdrawal?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules, payment-gateways

I'm implementing a site where users pay for submissions and reviewers get paid. [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) with [Commerce Credits](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_credits) allows me to buy credits using Paypal and to pay on site with credits for submitting content.

Reviewers receive credits for performing the review, when they reach a certain amount I want them to offer the possibility to withdraw credits through Paypal.

I had a look at modules like [Commerce Funds](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_funds) (broken) and [Commerce-Marketplace](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_marketplace) (withdrawal not implemented yet) and [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/) (not public anymore), did I miss anything?

Is there anything I can do to automatize this process with rules? I could transfer credits to a withdrawal user account and manually make the transaction with Paypal. Any hints how to automatize this process and trigger a Paypal payment to users credit card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this can be done, but it won't be easy. There will be quite some components and you will have to write some code. Disclaimer is that I have not tested anything of this code, but I hope this to be useful to you.

This example is based on the `commerce_funds_withdraw_action()` on line 932 of the [Commerce Funds Withdraw Module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce_funds/tree/modules/commerce_funds_withdraw/commerce_funds_withdraw.module?h=7.x-2.x), part of Commerce Funds.

Most important is this part, which performs the actual transfer using [PayPal Mass Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/mass-pay/) (Read [the integration guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayOverview/) for details about PayPal business accounts and contacting customer support to enable the feature.):

```
$response = commerce_paypal_api_request($payment_method, $nvp);
if($response['ACK'] == 'Success') {
  $withdraw->status = 'Transfered';
  $amount_paypal = $withdraw->amount;
  $withdraw->amount = commerce_currency_decimal_to_amount($withdraw->amount, $withdraw->currency_code);
  commerce_funds_withdraw_save($withdraw);
  $amount = array(
    'amount' => $amount_paypal,
    'currency_code' => $withdraw->currency_code,
    'reference' => $withdraw->uid,
  );
  commerce_funds_debit(user_load($withdraw->uid), $amount);
  drupal_set_message(t('Money were successfully transferred to @user_email.', array('@user_email' => $user->mail)), 'status');
}
```

If we remove all commerce funds transaction tracking, we are left with:

```
$response = commerce_paypal_api_request($payment_method, $nvp);
if($response['ACK'] == 'Success') {

  // Deduct credits from the account here, or do it in Rules later.

  drupal_set_message(t('Money was successfully transferred'), 'status');
}
```

The actual communication with the API is handled by [`commerce_paypal_api_request()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce_paypal!commerce_paypal.module/function/commerce_paypal_api_request/7), a function of the [Commerce PayPal](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_paypal) module, which requires 2 parameters;

- `$payment_method`: The payment method instance array associated with this API request.
- `$nvp`: The set of name-value pairs describing the transaction to submit. (See [MassPay API Using NVP](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayUsingAPI/#masspay-api-using-nvp) of the API documentation.)

Since there is no offical payment method to use, we create a custom payment method option:

```
$payment_method = array(
  'settings' => array(
    // Fill these to match the data configured with PayPal
    'server' => '',
    'api_username' => '',
    'api_password' => '',
    'api_signature' => '',
    'log' => array(
      'request' => FALSE, // Log outgoing request TRUE/FALSE.
      'response' => FALSE, // Log response from PayPal TRUE/FALSE.
    ),
  ),
);
```

And the NVP:

```
$nvp = array(
  'METHOD' => 'MassPay',
  'EMAILSUBJECT' => 'Withdraw',
  'CURRENCYCODE' => $currency_code,
  'RECEIVERTYPE' => 'EmailAddress',
  'L_EMAIL0' => $receiver_email,
  'L_AMT0' =>  $amount,
);
```

Now for getting this all together in a custom module and a Rules actions:

Create a `rules_paypal_deposit` folder for your module, with the following files:

rules_paypal_deposit.info:

```
name = Rules PayPal Deposit
description = Deposit funds to a paypal account using rules.
core = 7.x
dependencies[] = rules
dependencies[] = commerce_paypal
```

rules_paypal_deposit.module:

```
<?php
/* 
 * This function performs the actual transfer
 */
function rules_paypal_deposit_do_deposit($receiver_email, $amount, $currency_code) {
  $payment_method = array(
    'settings' => array(
      // Fill these to match the data configured with PayPal
      'server' => '',
      'api_username' => '',
      'api_password' => '',
      'api_signature' => '',
      'log' => array(
        'request' => FALSE, // Log outgoing request TRUE/FALSE.
        'response' => FALSE, // Log response from PayPal TRUE/FALSE.
      ),
    ),
  );

  $nvp = array(
    'METHOD' => 'MassPay',
    'EMAILSUBJECT' => 'Withdraw',
    'CURRENCYCODE' => $currency_code,
    'RECEIVERTYPE' => 'EmailAddress',
    'L_EMAIL0' => $receiver_email,
    'L_AMT0' =>  $amount,
  );

  $response = commerce_paypal_api_request($payment_method, $nvp);
  if($response['ACK'] == 'Success') {

    // Deduct credits from the account here, or do it in Rules later.

    drupal_set_message(t('Money was successfully transferred'), 'status');
  }
}
```

rules_paypal_deposit.rules.inc:

```
<?php
/**
 * Implement hook_rules_action_info()
 */
function rules_paypal_deposit_rules_action_info() {
  $actions = array(
    'rules_paypal_deposit_actions_deposit' => array(
      'label' => t('Transfer funds to a PayPal account'),
      'group' => t('Rules PayPal Deposit'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'receiver_email' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => t('E-mail to transfer to.'),
        ),
        'amount' => array(
          'type' => 'decimal',
          'label' => t('Amount to transfer (format: 12.34)'),
        ),
        'currency_code' => array(
          'type' => 'text',
          'label' => t('3 Letter currency of the transfer, see <a href="@url">the PayPal documentation</a>', array('@url' => url('https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/currency_codes/'))),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
  return $actions;
}

/** 
 * The action for rules_paypal_deposit_actions_deposit
 */
function rules_paypal_deposit_actions_deposit($receiver_email, $amount, $currency_code) {
  rules_paypal_deposit_do_deposit($receiver_email, $amount, $currency_code)
}
```

You can choose to add the PayPal API settings `server`, `api_username`, `api_password` and `api_signature` as Rules parameters as well and add the parameters to `rules_paypal_deposit_actions_deposit()` and `rules_paypal_deposit_do_deposit()`. Or just define them in the code.

---

I really hope this is of use to you. It was written in a bit of spare time because I thought it was a nice puzzle. Do not get mad if it doesn't work ;)

Obviously this needs proper testing on the PayPal API sandbox first.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive guide. I'll follow your steps and come back to you in the next days.

Comment: @geraldo, you managed to get this to work?

Comment: I'm on it, but don't have time to go on with it till next week. Till now your code looks promising and I wanted you to get the bounty ;)

Comment: Much appreciated :). Please let me know the outcome in the end.